# Kurento OneToMany With Rooms

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, github, webrtc, kurento

I look at this link 
https://github.com/BitOfUniverse/kurento-one2many-with-rooms/issues/1
and decided to run on my local machine via VMvare on Ubuntu Server 14.04 TLS

Before start to run this,
I install KMS 6 on ubuntu via this referance page.

**doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html#migrating-from-kms-v5-to-v6**

After KMS install, I follow the this link at below as referance

**doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2many.html**

My installation step for this link a little different

Here is the my installation steps:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g bower
```

After this step

I follow these

```
git clone https://github.com/BitOfUniverse/kurento-one2many-with-rooms.git
cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2many-call
git checkout 6.6.0
npm install
```

At there I used your git adress: git clone https://github.com/BitOfUniverse/kurento-one2many-with-rooms.git

Until these steps everthing looks fine. But when I run this command

```
npm start
```

I get the following error on log file

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
>   '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ] 2 info using npm@2.15.1 3 info using
>   node@v0.10.48 4 verbose node symlink /usr/bin/node 5 verbose
>   run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ] 6 info prestart
>   kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev 7 info start
>   kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev 8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle
>   true 9 info kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev Failed to exec start
>   script 10 verbose stack Error: kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev start:
>   node server.js 10 verbose stack Exit status 8 10 verbose stack at
>   EventEmitter.
>   (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16) 10 verbose
>   stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17) 10 verbose stack at
>   ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14) 10
>   verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17) 10 verbose stack
>   at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16) 10 verbose stack at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5) 11
>   verbose pkgid kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev 12 verbose cwd
>   /home/can/kurento-one2many-with-rooms 13 error Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
>   14 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" 15 error node
>   v0.10.48 16 error npm v2.15.1 17 error code ELIFECYCLE 18 error
>   kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev start: node server.js 18 error Exit
>   status 8 19 error Failed at the kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev start
>   script 'node server.js'. 19 error This is most likely a problem with
>   the kurento-one2many-call package, 19 error not with npm itself. 19
>   error Tell the author that this fails on your system: 19 error node
>   server.js 19 error You can get information on how to open an issue for
>   this project with: 19 error npm bugs kurento-one2many-call 19 error Or
>   if that isn't available, you can get their info via: 19 error 19 error
>   npm owner ls kurento-one2many-call 19 error There is likely additional
>   logging output above. 20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

My question is that, What Am I wrong? When I try to run example on Kurento, there isn't any error. But at there I get these error.

Also, I try to install socket.Io and etc. when I get error, but not solve my problem.

I found on the internet that 8080 port problem and kill apps on this port on cmd but still I have error.

What can I do? If you help me, I will be very happy.

Thaks a lot of your answer, have a nice and hapy day :) :) :)

Best Rigards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `postinstall` script you need to run after building the project (`npm run postinstall`). On lines 34 & 35 of project `readFileSync` uses relative path which doesn't work. You can fix that with `path.join` or simply hardcode full path. Also file names used for SSL keys are different from the ones on github and should be changed.

After all you may build the project but it doesn't work. [Here](https://github.com/Xaqron/kurento-one2many-with-rooms) is a refined fork.